# Filling XHTML fields in already made PDF file and adding image into it using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf, fpdi

I have got a PDF file that have an XHTML form with multiple input fields. I have to use this PDF file as template and fill those fields with user submitted data. I have searched over the internet and found a script called FPDI that can be used with FPDF and TCPDF. But I am unable to get it working as it produces some parsing error:

> fpdi parser file: the encoding used in the PDF file is not supported in the free version

Anyone there who has done work like this. Kindly help me out in this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: it gives error of fpdi parser file that the encoding used in the PDF file is not supported in the free version.

Comment: .. then you need to buy the script.

Comment: Is there anyother solution? Have you worked on putting texts or images to a PDF file?